# GDAL, ogr2ogr "Cannot find proj.db" Error

Tags: geojson, gdal, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I've tried to extract certain country from the world shp file from natural earth.

I am currently using windows 10, so I installed python 3.7, gdal to use the ogr2ogr.

I typed the below code in the command to extract the south korea

> ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "geonunit='South Korea'" korea-geo.json
>   ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp

But the below errors are coming out.

> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
>
> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db

I already set up the environmental variables for Gdal..

> C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data
>
> C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 20):

Check your environment_variable:

```
setx GDAL_DATA "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data"

setx GDAL_DRIVER_PATH "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins"

setx PROJ_LIB "C:\Program Files\GDAL\projlib"

setx PYTHONPATH "C:\Program Files\GDAL\"
```

Comment: Determinant variable is PROJ_LIB, it must point the directory that contains proj.db

Answer (score 8):

Adding PROJ_DEBUG=3 to your environment_variable is very useful.  The error message will then tell you where PROJ is expecting the file.

Answer (score 6):

You might need to set the `PROJ_LIB` environment variable. But I'm not sure where that data lives on your system. It could also be affected by how you installed GDAL.

If you go into your `C:\Program Files\GDAL` directory, do you have a folder called `proj`? If so, see if it has `proj.db` file in it. If it does, that's your PROJ_LIB path value. You might also find it in some kind of `share` folder.

If you don't find it nested somewhere in your GDAL directory, try searching your system for the `proj.db` file, and ,if you find it, set that directory (*NOT* the full file path) as your `PROJ_LIB` value, reboot, and see if things start working.

Answer (score 5):

**Add these commands to your code at the beginning before importing GDAL**. **Your issue will be solved**.

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:\\Users\\Sai kiran\\anaconda3\\envs\\sai\\Library\\share\\proj'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = 'C:\\Users\\Sai kiran\\anaconda3\\envs\sai\\Library\\share'

import gdal
```

Search for the location of your `proj.db` file in your anaconda directory and replace the same location with `C:\\Users\\Sai kiran\\anaconda3\\envs\\sai\\Library\\share\\proj`in the above command. Also, replace the location of `gdal` folder in the anaconda directory as in the above example.

Comment: the first line was all I needed in my case. All users should be aware that moving code between machines will require the directory location to be changed here.